# Serial Port on Raspberry Pi 3 ttys0

Tags: python, serial, pi-3

I have a Raspberry Pi B and a Raspberry Pi 3. I am trying to get the Raspberry Pi 3's serial port working. I have put a jumper across pins 8 and 10 to check the serial port is working.

I've executed the following code:

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate = 9600, timeout = 2)

port.write("test data")

time.sleep(1)

rcv = port.read(9)
print "received", rcv
```

My problem is that I'm not receiving anything.

I have tried the same code on /dev/ttyAMA0 on the Pi B and it works fine.

I have disabled the console from using the serial port in raspi-config and rebooted.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3/45571#45571

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have switched to using /dev/serial0 and introduced the core_freq=250 line to no avail.

Comment: Having the same problem, only using Cpp and wiringPi serial. Similarly I tested it with Pi 2 and the code was working but Pi 3 seems to require some tricks.

Comment: where is your "while Ture:" what was the error exactly?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing `enable_uart=1` in `/boot/config.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because in RPI3 ttyS0 is disabled by default. enable the ttyS0 in file
sudo nano /boot/config.txt and at the bottom of file change 0 to 1 to enable ttyS0
enable_uart=1 and reboot.

I followed this: https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the login shell is off and that the harwdare is enable: Use the raspi-config for that. the login shell keeps changing the permission of your port and will cause problems

check the group of /dev/ttyS0 with the command ls -la /dev/ttyS0. The group should be dialout. If not, setup the proper permission with sudo chgrp dialout /dev/ttyS0

Answer (score -1):

first, list all your serial files:

```
$ ls -l /dev/serial*
```

then, change `/dev/ttyS0` to `/dev/serial0` if your serial0 is your ttyS0 device.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to the question, and probably not a good idea.  If you want to use a different name, use a symlink (`ln -s /dev/ttyS0 /dev/serial0`), don't move or delete the original node.